# How can I rotate a GameObject based on slider input?

Tags: c#, slider, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate a GameObject with the help of slider input. I created a slider properly. I am able to change the position of GameObject, but when I am trying to rotate this GameObject with the Slider, it is not happening. Here is my code:

```
public GameObject gameObject;
private float m_currentValue = 20.0f;
void OnGUI() {
    m_currentValue  = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(35, 75, 200, 30), m_currentValue , 0.0F,  50.0F);
}

void Update(){}
```

How can I rotate a GameObject based on a slider's value?

Comment: That can't be your entire code. Where are you attempting to rotate the object? Show us. If you do, we can tell you what's going wrong. Right now you're simply asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to rotate the GameObject, that's why I asked here. I know we'll use "transform.rotation". But how to use I don't know. So please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rotate a GameObject, your best bet is to use a [Transform's](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html) [localEulerAngles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html). Don't go modifying the [rotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) directly. That is a quaternion, not a rotation in degrees. Even if you know what quaternions do, manipulating them directly is unintuitive at the very best.

So knowing that, you don't need to do a while lot more to your code. Just make sure it's a proper [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) and do something like the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float currentRotation = 20.0f;

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        currentRotation = GUI.HorizontalSlider(new Rect(35, 75, 200, 30), currentRotation , 0.0f,  50.0f);
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, currentRotation, 0.0f);
    }

}
```

This, in line with your pseudo-code, rotates the object which as that script between 0 and 50 degrees around its Y axis, based on the slider input.

Comment: Can you tell me @Bart, how can I rotate the GameObject with the help of NGUI Slider. Actually it is giving me trouble. If you can then please help me.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that have been written for or are part of NGUI. Several demo scenes that show sliders. Just figure out how to get the current sliderValue and feed that to the angles. One note, this no longer has to be put in an OnGUI. Try it, and if you can't figure it out, ask a clear question about it, showing what you've tried.

Comment: Actually I am using NGUI, and I am using a slider of NGUI. There is one class UISlider.cs. So I have a GameObject which I want to rotate with the help of NGUI Slider. But I am not able to connect my object with NGUI Slider. Even I am not getting any tutorial threw which I can connect my Object to NGUI Slider.

Comment: Depending on the version of NGUI there is an OnValueChange or onChange event you can hook into. Read through the documentation, look at the various examples of sliders and if you can't figure it out, ask a new question. But please educate yourself first. Don't ask us to do the work for you. NGUI and its support site have plenty of information.

Comment: Ok Sorry @Bart. I'll check on it's support site

Comment: If you do ask a question about it, make sure to accurately state the version of NGUI you're using. There have been major changes between the latest paid version and the available free version. So answers will be different depending on the version.

Comment: I got the solution of my problem, without asking any Question, thanks for guiding me @Bart...:)